# Is it better to use an unsuitable hashing algorithm instead of none at all?

Tags: passwords, hash

I have to store passwords on a system which doesn't offer any of the algorithms recommended for hashing passwords (e.g. bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2). Would it be better to use an unsuitable algorithm (e.g. SHA-1 or SHA-2 family) before using none?

---

*Additional Information*: I will be the only one storing passwords on that system, so I can 1) guarantee that none of the passwords will be used twice and 2) ensure that the passwords will have a very high entropy.

Comment: So you are generating the passwords and managing them? They are not user passwords? Does the authentication mechanism exist already or is this a new feature?

Comment: Do you have the ability to *stretch* the algorithm - to apply the same algorithm many times? If so, do that at a minimum.

Comment: It seems like you have a high degree of control over the passwords to be stored.. Do you not have a similar level of control over *how* they are stored?  Can you not choose to find something better?

Comment: I'm confused. If you're adding the authentication code, how do you not have the ability to pull in a library that implements newer hashing protocols? I'm also wondering if you're doing something like added an admin user to a device that it then distributed? I think this question lacks enough detail to really be answerable. Please provide more details about what you're implementing that will contain the password (a web interface, an IoT device, whatever) and why you need to lock anything down. (If you're distributing a device, then there's no point in even having the password.)

Comment: No, that presents a false sense of security, which is even worse, luckily there's encryption services you can interface with, here's one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html

Comment: If you truly cannot use any of the algorithms you should use (bcrypt, scrypt, et al), then at the very least use salt and key stretching with a large number (10's of thousands) of iterations. But seriously, you should find a way to use an appropriate algorithm. SHA-1 has been theoretically broken due a remote chance of collisions. It probably isn't broken in practice as collisions are extremely unlikely. Nevertheless if you're going to do something like this, use SHA-256 or SHA-512 instead.

Comment: @RandomUs1r You can only use online encryption services like that if you're guaranteed that your system will be online any time it is used. This wasn't specified, but it may not be guaranteed.

Comment: Consider using a lightweight Docker container to install all the necessary libraries, then use the container to hash.

Comment: Why do you mention that the pw's are unique? That shouldn't be relevant at all.

Comment: Also, ensuring password uniqueness is somehow a flaw rather than a security (if at all): you will have to indicate to a user trying to re-use an existing password that it cannot be used, therefore giving them the indication that this password exists in your database already (or at least this conclusion is easy to come to)

Comment: We design software to fit within certain constraints.  You have two competing constraints: security for your users and technology environment which cannot hash passwords.  Solution: change your constraints.  Which do you value more, keeping users' passwords safe or sticking with particular technology?

Comment: The "additional information" raises more questions. Storing hashes doesn't "ensure the passwords have high entropy" and if your system forbids different users from having the same password ("none of the passwords will be used twice") that's a terrible idea. You've given an attacker an oracle that can tell them if a password is already in use on the system. Do not do this!

Comment: To put my above comment another way: you haven't specified your threat model. It's somewhere between extremely difficult and impossible to evaluate a security measure without understanding what threat it's supposed to defend from. Your details don't really line up with any standard cases for when you need accounts at all for us to make educated guesses about the threats you have in mind. The result is that you're getting answers from the assumption of the typical "end user creates an account and has some resources that need protecting" use case.

Comment: @LaurentS. If the password cannot be used, then it is of no risk to know it. Arguably knowing this reduces the attack space a little, but since you already had to put in some work to determine it, there doesn't seem to be any net gain for the attacker.

Comment: @LaurentS: not only you've given the attacker an oracle, by ensuring password uniqueness your essentially telling the attacker that you're not storing your password correctly. With proper password hashing, it should be impossible to tell if two accounts are using the same password. That's almost like an invitation to probe more.

Comment: @LieRyan : indeed. That's probably the reason why I actually never encountered such a feature among the many wrongs I've seen hitherto.

Comment: Is it better to close the door of your house with a duct tape instead of leaving it open when you leave (if you don't have a lock)?

Answer (score 115):

The real answer to your question is simply do not store the passwords there if you cannot properly protect them.

"The system does not support proper password hashing algorithms" is not a valid excuse to compromise the security of your users. Either find a way to properly hash passwords using a strong and properly configured algorithm or do not store them.

But to provide a direct answer to your question: yes, something is better than nothing. SHA-1 or SHA-2 is definitely an improvement over plaintext.

To answer the "then where should the passwords go?" question - Based on the phrasing I am assuming there is a new feature/request for the software that requires the system to store passwords.

If the system cannot properly and securely store passwords (by modern security standards) then I (personally) would reject the request. Intentionally practicing poor security because of legacy system constraints or to appease a  business use case is bad security practice. I would inform whoever made the request that I have two viable options:

1. We have to completely overhaul the system to one that supports modern security practices (such as proper cryptographic password hashing).
2. I simply cannot add the new feature/request to the existing system for it would compromise security.

Comment: I updated my question with additional information, does that help?

Comment: @JFB Not overly. The extra info is good, and means that the damage done by compromising weakly hashed, strong, never re-used passwords is obvious less harmful than compromising genuine ordinary users passwords but doesn't help focus my answer too much.

Comment: What if my boss wants the system to be able to actually remind and not just reset passwords? They want it so badly they are willing to sacrifice security for it. How would you respond to such a request?

Comment: @Gherman as with anything, you do a cost/benefit analysis and let the decision-maker and risk owner decide.

Comment: @dFrancisco refusing to add a new feature is fine if you are the system owner, but you have no basis to refuse if you are the admin or the developer. ***Advise and educate*** is your role as a security professional.

Comment: It would be better to rephrase your refusal in *business terms* rather than just the vague "security." E.g., "We would be knowingly storing sensitive data in a way that makes it easier for an attacker to obtain it. This may be a violation of GDRP/HIPPA/any-relevant-standard-the-company-might-get-in-trouble-for-breaking and open us up to legal consequences." But this *is* the correct course of action for generic user management.

Comment: @Wildcard let's not get crazy with the leaps in logic, the "slippery slopes" and the ad absurdum. There is a large field of play between "not refusing" and "should add the feature". Please take any further comments to chat.

Comment: While a weak hash is slightly better than nothing, a *salted* weak hash is significantly better than nothing. Nothing in the question or this answer refer to salting so it's probably a good idea to make a specific mention of that.

Comment: "something is better than nothing" is only true if the something is BETTER than nothing (and doesn't give off the implication that it is more effective) - for example unsalted MD5 or ROT13 or whatever.

Comment: @Joe I'll give you ROT13, but unsalted MD5 *is* better than nothing, and salted MD5 is dramatically better than unsalted SHA3.

Comment: @MartinBonner If it's better at all, it's so trivially "better" that we can (and should, to avoid misleading people) neglect the difference.

Comment: @Gherman I respond by saying, "You're opening yourself up to a world of liability. Our insurance might even deny claims based on that kind of negligence (https://www.gbainsurance.com/avoiding-cyber-claim-denials), and any lawsuit for damages against us would stand a much better chance of succeeding. The secure alternative is a password reset system, and I would be happy to implement that instead." The boss may not understand security, but they darn well understand losing money.

Answer (score 48):

Yes, a weak cryptographic hash is better than no hash.

The reasons for hashing your passwords are, in the event that your password db is stolen:

1. Prevent the attacker from trivially obtaining the plaintext passwords.
2. Prevent the attacker from knowing which users have the same password (this is accomplished via giving each user a unique salt.

1 is an arms race: you want to use a bigger, slower hash function so that it costs the attacker more in electricity to perform the brute-force hash cracking. A single iteration of SHA-1/2 is better than no hash because the attacker has to do *some* cracking. A single iteration of *salted* SHA-1/2 will force them to do some cracking *without being able to use pre-computed rainbow tables*. Moving up to the fancier password hashes (argon2, bcrypt or the older scrypt, pbkdf2) with a higher work factor will crank up the electricity costs of the crack even further.

Using any salted cryptographic hash (even ones not recommended for passwords, like SHA-1, SHA-2) will give the benefits of 2.

---

At its core, PBKDF2 is just iterated and salted SHA-1/2, so I would do some googling for PBKDF2 implementations, and build your wrapper around SHA-1/2 that emulates it (or better, go all the way and actually implement PBKDF2).

Comment: I'd suggest including Argon2 in your list, since it's currently the preferred algorithm when GPUs or FPGA/ASIC cracking are in your threat model (which they should be).

Comment: +1. Note that this actually depends on how long your user base is willing to wait for auth (and how much load your auth systems can take in parallel). At the sub-100ms mark, bcrypt is actually more resistant to bruteforce. Only above ~1s/auth does Argon2 become superior. Refs:  https://twitter.com/Sc00bzT/status/1063895918246862848, https://twitter.com/Sc00bzT/status/1041875128311840768

Comment: Is it really? You tell me you securely store my data, I give you sensitive data to store, you then lose the data because it's not actually secure, wouldn't it be better to be up front and state you're not securely storing the data in the first place? ...idealistically speaking

Comment: SHA-1 isn't breached against preimage yet. It will hold.

Comment: @RandomUs1r What do you mean "not securely storing the data"? PBKDF2, while a bit old, is still considered secure if you use 10,000 iterations of SHA-1 or SHA-2 and unique per-user salts. If you have a SHA-2 primitive available, then you can build PBKDF2 (or something which is functionally equivalent). Please back up your statement that this is only an illusion of security.

Comment: "Using any cryptographic hash will give the benefits of 2." I suppose it should go without saying, but it might be worth adding "salted" after "any".

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of the PBKDF2 implementation. But assuming you have a solid implementation of the underlying hashing algorithm like SHA-1 or SHA-2, is it acceptable to implement PBKDF2 on your own if the developers are no crypto experts?

Comment: @JFB I think so, but I wouldn't give it to the new hire. Looking at the PBKDF2 spec or an open-source implementation and applying a medium amount of attention to detail would do the trick. Put another way: I would trust myself to implement something PBKDF2-like in a day or two and use it in prod. I would under no circumstances trust myself to implement SHA-2 in under a month.

Answer (score 30):

As others have said, try to find a strong standalone implementation in your platform's language if at all possible.

But if you can't use a strong hash ... then you should **definitely** still hash your users' passwords, even with a weak hash - because **even a weak hash will protect a strong password**.

When tools like hashcat can guess *billions of passwords per second*, weak hashes won't protect weak passwords. But if one of your security-conscious users selects an uncrackable password like 'SDXBZsRVBKVnXznpLTBMIKhTX' or 'afferently-imitatee-snowmelt-heirdom-leeching' ... then even a weak hash like SHA1 will still put that password out of reach of a bruteforce attack.

By using even a weak hash, you can at least enable your savvy users to protect themselves *even though your system is weak*. (And if you have the ability to *stretch* - to use the same algorithm thousands of times in a row - this will slow down the attacker as well).

But your savvy users won't be reusing passwords, so even this is of limited value (except for "semi-savvy" users who have picked passwords strong enough to resist bruteforce, but may be reusing that password elsewhere or using a human-parseable password selection scheme ... so using even a weak hash will protect these users as well).

Your best option for all users is to find a way to use a strong hash.

[Edit: the OP has updated the question to indicate that **they are the only user of the system, and can set an arbitrarily random password** (which seems pretty odd to me; I don't know of a system with such a strange combination of "I am the only user", "I can only pick from a few hashing algorithms", and "All of the hashing algorithms are weak"). Either way, this makes my concern about protecting general users' weak passwords irrelevant for this specific question. Other answers should clarify at the beginning of their answers that they are giving advice that would normally be pretty bad, and is only applicable to this very specific question.]

[Edit 2: Note that "weak hash" isn't the same thing as "bad hash". An example of a bad hash would be descrypt (because it truncates passwords at 8 characters). So even if your password is strong, an 8-character descrypt hash can be bruteforced in 10 days or less on a prosumer-grade (6 GPU) cracking system.]

Comment: I updated my question with additional information adressing your point of being able to at least protect strong, unique passwords

Comment: *Password reuse* is when users choose to use the same password across multiple sites (Facebook, their bank, etc.) ... not when two users are using the same password on the *same* site.

Comment: I agree, but with the added caveat that you should NOT use SHA-1 to produce a digest of any sensitive data (like passwords) without using random salt to address password re-use, plus key stretching.

Comment: Upvote for ``even a weak hash will protect a strong password``

Answer (score 16):

**SHA-2 in this particular case is just as secure as PBKDF/scrypt/bcrypt. Iterations are unnecessary and wasteful. Generate high-entropy (256 bit) passwords and forget about KDFs and even salts.**

In fact, it makes more sense to use SHA-2 than PBKDF because there is no existing platform implementation of the algorithm and "rolling your own crypto" is a no-no.

That's quite a strong statement. The essence here in the question is that the OP has full control of the passwords he stores on the system and knows that he will be the only one storing passwords on the system.

[Signal](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) makes use of a construction called HKDF in its double-ratchet algorithm, which essentially applies the hashing algorithm for only one iteration.

**Why is this okay?**

Password KDFs exist for precisely one reason: low-entropy passwords. Most people won't remember a 128- or 256-bit key generated from a CSRNG in their heads. I'd venture that most people can remember at most a 40-bit random string for a long enough period of time to use it.

Pretty much all hash functions (even MD4, MD5, and SHA-1, but since you said you have SHA-2 on the platform, let's be safe here) have a feature called [preimage resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), which is good enough for your application since you control all of the passwords that get stored on your system. This means that it is computationally infeasible, given a hash, to generate something that hashes to the same hash.

Simplifying a bit, the most practical way to generate a preimage for one of these hash functions is to keep trying inputs. There are a few [examples](https://iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2009/54790136/54790136.pdf) of attacks that do slightly better than brute force, but they're totally infeasible. Now, if the password/key you chose to put into the hash function only has 16 bits of entropy, this resistance property won't do you much, because the attacker will be able to try all 65536 different inputs you could have put in.

**Why control of the password matters**

Think less of the things that you're putting in as "passwords" but more as cryptographic keys. As long as you are hashing keys that have entropy greater than or equal to the number of bits output by your choice of hash function (for SHA-256, that's 256 bits), then you're totally fine just running one iteration of the hash over it to prevent key extraction. The preimage resistance of the hash combined with the high entropy of your key means that an attacker simply cannot guess the value that you put in. There's no need for the thousands of iterations or arguing with the business side or reasoning about an abstract attack to not-so-receptive bosses. FPGA/ASIC resistance is a moot point when you have to guess a 256-bit input into the hash function.

**Recommendations**

Generate your "passwords" with a hardware RNG or a CSPRNG and promptly destroy any seed material that could be used to recover any internal state and therefore the passwords. Make sure that these are 256 bits long. If your system doesn't support non-alphanumeric or non-ASCII passwords, then *after* you generate the 256 bits, encode it in base-64 or base-26 or binary if you like. (This means that the actual passwords that you submit will be longer than 32 bytes, but this doesn't help entropy much.)

Treat these passwords like cryptographic keys -- ideally, they would be stored on hardware tokens. A hardware password manager works very well for this purpose. Store the SHA-256 hashes in your system, and verify the passwords by hashing and comparing. You should reject all attempted passwords that do not match your generation criterion (an example would be a user-selected password < 256 bits), even if the hashes match, and you should not allow anyone to set a password that did not come from a CSRNG. This should be 
documented. Even better is if you add some obscure checksum byte at the end of the passwords that you generate that is verified by the platform before it allows you to set the password. This should deter all but the most hilariously incompetent people from putting anything less than a cryptographic key on your platform.

**Public Key Cryptography**

Your use case is a bit odd. Most places maintain passwords because setting up a PKI and dealing with end-users is very difficult, especially with things like public keys. Since you seem to be the only one entering passwords into the system, maybe it would make more sense to store Ed25519 or ECDSA public keys on the system and write code there that implements a challenge-response protocol (a simple one is sign this 256-bit value -- but be careful that you don't reuse these keys, as someone might trick you into signing away your Bitcoin or a criminal confession). The device that would interface with your system here and maintain the private keys probably has a strong implementation of public-key cryptography and would have no problem authenticating itself. Your "roll my own" implementation of the signature verification could be the least secure in the world in terms of side-channel attacks (think of putting its entire state on a billboard or the blockchain), as long as it gives the correct answer, and you would be perfectly fine, as the verification algorithm simply has no access to the private keys.

Comment: I ... um ... Most of this answer appears to be about **completely** unrelated cryptography topics and/or highly misguided. The remainder is disconnected from how password-storage techniques actually work. Salting and iterations are 100% how passwords are securely stored. Further, recommending that someone use straight SHA-2 is *very* bad advice; my 6x 1080 rig can guess 18.7 *billion passwords per second* of SHA-2, but only 95,000 per second of bcrypt cost 5 (and bcrypt cost 12 or higher is the current modern target)

Comment: @RoyceWilliams I'm not a security professional, but if I understand OP correctly, they're advocating that users put in no less then 256 bits of entropy for passwords. Even at your 18.7 billion attempts a second, if my back of the napkin math is correct (`(2^256) / 18.700.000.000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365`) then you'd still need 1.963*e+59 years to try all combinations, which I think would qualify as "computationally infeasible" even if you assume that highly optimized hardware would be 100.000 times more efficient.

Comment: In other words, to a non security professional like me, it would seem that the answerer is correct in that every preimage resistant hashing algorhitm could be considered safe if you can guarantee non reused 256 bit entropy passwords.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams yeah, I think the main issue is that the overall suggestion JohnAdams is making could be a bit more clear.  It seems he's suggesting to not use passwords at all but rather to use key-based authentication.  In that case, indeed, neither iterations nor salting matter.

Comment: To put it simply, very long, securely generated passwords are essentially what cryptographic keys are.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams You seem to misunderstand the gist of the answer. If your passwords have enough entropy, then a KDF is unnecessary. KDFs are used because most passwords are low-entropy. When your passwords get to entropy levels comparable to those of cryptographic keys, it really doesn't matter how they're hashed, as long as the hash has preimage resistance.

Comment: All of that sounds great .. *if* you have the dramatically rare luxury of forcing all users to only use automatically generated passwords. As soon as users are allowed to pick their own passwords, all of the preceding reasoning is irrelevant. And making a sweeping initial general statement that a fast hash is as good as a slow hash sends exactly the opposite message from what we want sysadmins and developers to know: that *strong hashes protect weak passwords, and most users pick weak passwords*.

Comment: Note also that I gave my answer before the OP told us that they are the only user of the system. I've updated my question accordingly, and I suggest that all other answers be edited to make it *very* clear up front why this is an unusual corner case - otherwise, they are giving advice that is *very* bad for 99.9% of cases ... and many SE users will skim the question, go to the top answers, and come to exactly the opposite conclusion from the one that almost everyone needs.

Comment: My issue with this answer is that it can basically be summarized in two sentences: "Don't use passwords, use keys.  Keys can't be bruteforced so if you use keys then you don't have to worry as much about hashing."  This is certainly good security advice, and it is 100% true (keys are fare more secure and effectively can't be brute forced).  However, it is very unlikely to be helpful advice to the OP, as key-based logins also take some time to setup in a way that is convenient for the user.

Comment: In short, the OP is trying to get basic security in place with a minimal of trouble, and you are proposing an answer that gives amazing security with a large amount of trouble.  There is often a trade off between usability and security.  The OP is clearly trying to favor the usability side of that spectrum, and you're proposing a solution that gives high security at the cost of decreased usability.  Simply put: if he doesn't have time to setup a proper hashing algorithm, then I doubt he has time to find a hardware-based RNG.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mike and Royce in their answers, and don't feel the need to repeat what they covered well.  However I wanted to more directly address this comment of yours:

> Additional Information: I will be the only one storing passwords on
>   that system, so I can 1) guarantee that none of the passwords will be
>   used twice and 2) ensure that the passwords will have a very high
>   entropy.

This piece of information is both important and not-important.  Here's why:

**The case for password hashing**

It's always important to remember *why* we hash passwords, and it all boils down to password reuse.  The reason why password hashing is so important is because when your system gets compromised and passwords are stolen, it isn't just access to your site that is compromised, but access to every site where your users have re-used the same email/password combination which (as we know) happens a lot.  Password hashing is about protecting users from themselves.  If absolutely everyone used strong and unique passwords on every site, then password hashing would be a lot less necessary.  It would still have some value because there are use cases where a hacker might gain read-only access to a database dump, so hashed passwords can provide some protection against attackers getting actual access to your system in. However, if people used strong and unique passwords everywhere then password hashing would become more of a secondary concern instead of the absolutely-critical necessity it is today.

So, if you can guarantee that every user of your system will only ever use strong and unique passwords (i.e. passwords that have not been used on other sites), then I think that even something simple like SHA2 would actually be a perfectly reasonable choice, regardless of whether or not better functions were available.

**BUT: changing business needs**

However, I would encourage you to double check your assumptions (that strong unique passwords will be the only ones ever in your system).  I've seen business needs change to often in the past to rely on assumptions like that in critical business areas (which this may not be - obviously I don't know what this does).  The problem is that business needs change.  Maybe it's just me, but in my experience things that were meant to be temporary or limited to just a couple people inevitably turn into critical business applications used by everyone in the company, and all of a sudden you have a weak password scheme protecting critical business infrastructure.  It won't always happen because people are **trying** to cut corners, but because 12 months down the road you forget that you didn't use a great password hash, or you leave and then next guy doesn't look into it, or you're under pressure to meet a deadline and you forget, or, or, or...

In my experience businesses end up having security breaches not because security is **hard** but because they don't understand the need for spending time (aka money) on good security practices and cut corners where they shouldn't.  Sure, right *now* a great password hashing scheme doesn't matter, but can you really guarantee that that won't change in the future?  If you don't have time to put in proper password hashing now, can you guarantee that when the needs change and it suddenly does matter, that you will have time to do it right then?

Of course at the end of the day every business needs to make money, and sometimes "Let's keep this simple for now to get this out the door" is a perfectly reasonable answer.  Just be careful though because making that decision too often is how companies end up with systems filled with security holes.  As a company you have to find that balance for yourself.  The trouble is that when companies chronically skimp on the security it is ultimately their customers that hurt the most.

Comment: +1 for "things that were meant to be temporary or limited to just a couple people inevitably turn into critical business applications"

Answer (score 2):

> I have to store passwords on a system which doesn't offer any of the algorithms recommended for hashing passwords (e.g. bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2). Would it be better to use an unsuitable algorithm (e.g. SHA-1 or SHA-2 family) before using none?

The strict answer to your question is yes.  The reason is that fast hashes won't protect weak passwords, but they will protect very strong ones, and that is strictly better than plaintext.

However, if you have SHA-1 or SHA-2 there are are very few (if any!) excuses not to use PBKDF2.  Yeah, the common advice is "don't roll your own crypto," but if you've got SHA-1 or SHA-2 that's already the key building block for PBKDF2, and **for the case of password hashing writing your own implementation of PBKDF2 can hardly be worse than not**.  Here's the relevant RFC and section:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2

When they say "pseudorandom function" you should use some HMAC variant (ideally HMAC-SHA-512, but any of them will do). Your library likely already has HMAC implementations, but if it doesn't, password hashing is again a case where implementing your own can't be worse than not.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, use the best algorithm you have access to. If you have several, you might combine them (note: concatenation of passwords, e.g. sha1(password)+md5sum(password), is more vulnerable to guessing, since an attacker could pick which hash they want to guess, but collisions are much less likely, since both passwords have to match. Do use random, different salt for each password.

**You say your system "doesn't offer any of the algorithms recommended for hashing passwords".  I would encourage you to reexamine that assumption.**

Almost every modern programming language has implementations of secure hashes. You do not necessarily need it implemented in a pre-made, pre-installed library - for example, if your program is written in C, you should be able to find implementations of any hash in C, as a stand-alone function. Even tiny processors like Arduino have bcrypt and PBKDF2, off the shelf. The extra labour involved is minimal. You could even implement it yourself (but be very careful, and test very thoroughly!).

I do not doubt that there are exceptions, but there aren't many.

Answer (score 0):

**YES, even low quality hash is much better than storing passwords in plaintext**

*If I understand you update, someone else will be doing the authentication (unrelated to you and your database), and you will use your password hash database only for duplicate password detection? Requirement of determining the password entropy would be based on plaintext, and is unrelated to storing password hashes, right?*

Then you can store in your hash database just a small part of calculated `sha2` hash of `salt`+`plaintext` (for example, storing only low 8 bytes of 32 bytes returned by sha256), which will be plenty enough to detect duplicates with no false positives in real life, but still not enough to allow the attacker to use rainbow tables to guess original password in case your database is stolen.

(Disclaimer: if you ARE doing authentication and not only duplicate password detection, than dropping part ot the hash would obviously be terrible idea!)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, using a weak hash is better than none.

I think you should also consider the administrative way. If you maintain the database (but are not allowed to change the structure, who knows why...) you should not see plain text passwords, even if you are the most integer person and would not do any harm with that information. Just like the proverb: Opportunity makes the thief.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitively better to use a simple hash than none (though seeing how you apparently *implement* the system, I fail to see what's hindering you from doing things properly).

However, given your "Additional information" edit, one might so bold as to say that you do not even need salt! That doesn't mean it's a good design and I wouldn't recommend that, but if you are serious about your guarantees, a simple secure hash of reasonable size is enough, strictly speaking.

Why does one make such a fuss about password storage in the first place? Usually, passwords are low-entropy, and even when hashed there's a fair chance of guessing a password, even moreso as hash functions are *very fast*, trivially parallelizable, and there exist rainbow tables which provide a cheap shortcut. So even being unreadable after being hashed, this doesn't necessarily mean that passwords are unrecoverable.
In principle, given infinite time, you could recover every password on every system (or at least a password that will work). That's just a consequence of the fact that there is a finite number of outputs to a hash function. So, in a quasi-exhaustive search, *some* input sequence must necessarily produce an output that works.
Luckily attackers do not have infinite time, so our job is to make sure they don't have a reasonable chance of finding an input sequence that works within finite time, and with a finite supply of energy.

Now... you say that you are the only user and you can *guarantee* that passwords are random and high entropy. This rules out most of the concerns about guessing.

Given a "reasonable" digest size, that means that the chance of finding the hash in a rainbow table is minimal (zero, more or less), and the chance of finding it by brute force is equally more or less zero. There's no way someone will break SHA-256 digest brute force, let alone SHA-512. That idea simply isn't compatible with our understanding of how physics work.
If the digest is large enough, and passwords are guaranteed (as you state) to be unique, random, high entropy... then actually you're just good to go with hashing once.

Now of course, normally a system should work reliably even if you *cannot* provide that guarantee (or *any* guarantee for that matter). Thus, it's not the very best design.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should be fine. SHA1 and 2 are still pretty strong for storing high entropy password hashes and will provide adequate protection from brute forcing. SHA2 provides better protection than SHA1.The vulnerabilities in SHA2 arn't relevant for this scenario since they relate to creating collisions where the initial plaintext is already known.

Comment: This is just wrong. https://www.pcworld.com/article/3173791/security/stop-using-sha1-it-s-now-completely-unsafe.html
https://dusted.codes/sha-256-is-not-a-secure-password-hashing-algorithm

Comment: Also... https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35642

Comment: Its right. The PC-World article talks about generating a collision from known plaintext. That's bad news for certain types of certificates or for file integrity but fine for passwords. The second one just says that weak unsalted passwords are easy to crack. This is true for all hashing algorithms and irrelevant in this scenario. The SE link says the same thing I did. Just make sure to implement the rest of the system correctly and use strong passwords.

Answer (score 0):

To go along with the excellent answers above, I want to give a complimentary but contrary answer:

**No**. Using a weak hash is **worse** than not using a hash at all.

A weak hash gives you the illusion of security.

While you and your managers might understand currently that the hash offers no real security, a manager or developer down the line may think the hash is secure. These people may decide to store additional information using the hash in question.

There is also the risk where management may not simply understand that the hash is not secure to begin with. When faced with a decision to invest in security development, they may decide "the current system is good enough" because it is hashed already, and hashing is considered best practice.